# How can I check for cluster patterns in a sequence of numbers and obtain the next value?

Tags: r, math, data-manipulation

Given a set of sequences

```
seq1 <- c(3,3,3,7,7,7,4,4)
seq2 <- c(17,17,77,77,3)
seq3 <- c(5,5,23)
```

How can we create a function to check this sequence for cluster patterns and predict the next value of the sequence which in this case would be 4,3, and 23 respectively.

Edit: The sequence should first be checked for cluster patterns, if it does not contain this class of pattern then the sequence should be ignored or passed onto another function

Edit 2: A pattern should be defined by more that 1 of the same consecutive number and always grouped consistently e.g 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3 is a pattern but 1,1,2,2,2,3,3 is not a pattern

Comment: is it `seq3` or `seq2`

Comment: How do you get 4, 3, and 23?

Comment: Define pattern. Should patterns always be of the same size (within a vector)? What would the next value be for `c(1,1,2,2,1,1,3,3)`?

Comment: Here next value is last value

Comment: I think the answer is very simple, just repeat the last number of your current sequence... `seq1[length(seq1)]`.... But if your example changes to say `c(3,3,3,7,7,7,1)` then @Shree has the answer...

Comment: But I wish to check the sequence first and if it does not follow a cluster pattern then to ignore it or pass it onto the next function

Comment: Add this to your question @BethanHuish

Comment: So do you want an initial if statement that checks the following? `rle_values <- rle(seq1)$lengths;
rle_values_limit <- rle_values[1:(length(rle_values)-1)];
all(rle_values == rle_values[1])`  So for a sequence like `c(1,1,2,2,3,3)`, you pass it through as there is a pattern, but for `c(1,1,2,3,3)` you wouldnt...

Comment: @HectorHaffenden, ah yes this is along the lines of what I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way with `rle` in base R which checks if all run-lengths, except last, are equal and if `TRUE` then repeats the last value such that it has same pattern as others -

```
rl <- rle(seq1)$lengths

# check if all run-lengths, except last, are equal
if(all(head(rl, -1) == rl[1])) {
  c(seq1, rep(seq1[length(seq1)], diff(range(rl))))
} else {
  # do something else
}


# [1] 3 3 3 7 7 7 4 4 4
```

The same approach applies for `seq2` and `seq3`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but is there a way to check the sequence input first to see if it follows a cluster pattern?

Comment: @BethanHuish You'll have to define what a pattern is? Is `c(3,3,3,2,2,4,4,4,4)` a pattern? Add more details, examples, and expected output for those examples in your post.

Comment: @Shree I think just add an if statement with something like my comment and I think thats it.

Comment: I am trying to to use this with the apply() function on a csv file with a list of these types of number patterns, is there any reason why its not working and giving me this error "Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (newX[, i])"?